# AIR with Android Emulator?

Tags: air, android-emulator

is it possible to debug AIR applications with the Android Emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is now possible by using *Target apk-debug* with the AIR 2.5 ADT.  from the AIR 2.5 release notes:

---

**Packaging targets**

The AIR Developer Tool (ADT) supports new target options for building Android application packages (APK files):

**Target apk:** Creates a release APK package suitable for distribution. (Packages created with this target cannot be installed on an Android emulator.)

**Target apk-emulator:** Creates a release-mode APK package for installation on an Android emulator.

**Target apk-debug:** Creates a debug-mode APK package that can be installed on both Android emulators and devices.